# cant read css and js includes after setting kohana to remove index.php in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, kohana, kohana-3.2

[image]http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls

following this tutorial, i managed to remove index.php from the url. I edited the "base_url" in **bootstrap.php** and the edited the .htaccess according to the tutorial. But now, I'm having a problem. my pages now can't load any of my css and js files included.

The picture there shows what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `assets` folder public. Do not store inside the application directory.

Comment: I'm new to this .htaccess thing. Somebody helped me on facebook and I just removed a line in my .htaccess file and its ok now

Comment: Actually he offered me two options and the other one is to put my assets outside the application folder. But the other solution is easier.

Comment: Exactly which was the line you removed? It is better to move your assets outside the application directroy.

Comment: # RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

Comment: yeah I think it is better to move the assets outside, because when i removed that particular line, I am now able to browse the kohana system files and others.